# Making a link that generates a tweet on Twitter

Tags: twitter, html-email

I've just looked online but couldn't find the answer:

Is it possible to include a link in an HTML e-mail, so that when a user clicks it, it takes them to post a pre-defined text on their Twitter account, e.g. "@username #hashtagterm This text comes up automatically for me to tweet"?

I guess that if a user isn't logged in, they'll have to go past the login screen and then arrive at the page where they can send the tweet, right?

As I said, it needs to work reliably in an email, so I guess it shouldn't have any javascript associated with it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, replacing the text with what you want:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=this+is+a+test
```

See [intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents)